# I have two arrays and I want to compare them in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays and assigned them some data:

```
const myFollowers = !followerLoading && (
    followersData.map((e) => e.requested_profile.Userlink )
)

const myFollowings = !followingLoading && (
followingData.map((e) => e.requesting_profile.Userlink)
)
```

They are dynamic and elements don't have a fixed value. This is the data stored for now:

```
myFollowers - ['Sandrine Debruyne', 'design-hotels', 'angel', 'manu-thomas']
myFollowing - ['angel', 'manu-thomas']
```

I want to compare the data in both elements such that if the strings in the arrays match, it should show "following", otherwise "Follow". I have tried this but it shows "following" every time, and I don't want that.... I want the element to be "Following" only if that particular element is present in that array:

```
const btntext = myFollowers.some(r=> myFollowings.includes(r))  ? "Following" : "Follow"
```

this btntext will be assigned to a button here:

```
!followerLoading && (
                        followersData.map((e) => {
                            const btntext = myFollowings.some(r=> myFollowers.includes(r))  ? "Following" : "Follow"
                        return(<>
                            <div className="data">
                            <Grid  templateColumns="repeat(2, 1fr)" width="100%" alignContent="center">
                            <GridItem w="100%" >
                            <Flex 
                            // maxWidth="100%"
                            mt="10px">
                                <Avatar
                                size={isTabletOrMobile ? "xs" : "sm"}
                                src={e.requested_profile.s3PicURL}
                                />
                                
                                <Text
                                w="100%"
                                wrap="off"
                                ml="5px"
                                isTruncated
                                fontSize={isTabletOrMobile ? "sm" : "md"}
                                >
                                    {e.requested_profile.Userlink}
                                </Text>
                            </Flex>
                            </GridItem>
                            <GridItem>
                                <Flex justifyContent="flex-end">
                                <Button
                                w="100px"
                                h="30px"
                                mt="8px"
                                width={isTabletOrMobile ? "50px" : "60px"}>
                                    {
                                        btntext
                                    }
                                </Button>
                                </Flex>
                            </GridItem>
                            </Grid>
                            </div>
                            </>
                        ) 
                    })
                    )
```

Comment: You're array some / array includes combination will correctly (albeit inefficiently) return true if it finds at least one value in the `Followers` list in the `Following` list. Are you certain your two arrays have data in them you expect? What do you mean "doesn't work"

Comment: _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_ ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: There are _four_ "followers" but only _one_ `btntext`. How should this work? o.O

Comment: What is the expected behavior? `myFollowers.some(r=> myFollowings.includes(r))` will show `Following` if there is at least one matching element, and `Follow` if there is exactly no matching elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  const myFollowers = ['Sandrine Debruyne', 'design-hotels', 'angel', 'manu-thomas']
  const myFollowing = ['angel', 'manu-thomas']

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {myFollowers && myFollowing && myFollowers.map(follower => (
<><p>{follower}</p> <button>{myFollowing.includes(follower) ? "Following" : "Follow"}</button></>
))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can run it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-kepler-l6enw

If you create your DOM, check if the myFollowing includes the current name of the user.

Comment: I have edited my question, can you please check again and help?

Comment: @PrathamSampat Can you set up an codesandbox with your data? Or share the git?